# How to hide view's results before applying exposed filter?

Tags: views

In a view I have some exposed filters.I would like the view to show no results before applying the exposed filter(s),but only after I have applied the exposed filter.By default,the view shows all the results.How can I achieve that?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could link to the view and pass a filter argument in the URL that doesn't have any results.

Or you could hide the exposed filters in a block. Also, create a "block" display for your view results.

Add the filter block to a page. Add the "results" block to the page but only show it for pages with "pagename?*".
That will hide your results block until filter values are passed through the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I also found these two articles that solve the problem:http://highrockmedia.com/blog/using-drupal-views-arguments-show-results-only-when-filter-used http://groups.drupal.org/node/50763

Comment: thanks. Looks like it's now built into views 3, just select "exposed form style: input required". Too easy ;-)

Comment: If you're using [Better Exposed Filters](https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters), there's a patch available over at [Add 'input required' option/functionality](https://drupal.org/node/1447730), but by the time you read this, it may already be committed. ;)