# How to NOT show results on view page

Tags: views

This is going to be a ridiculously simple question and after getting this crazy view working, I don't' know why I can't figure this out.

I have created a view from entityform and field collections.  Got everything working, displays what I want. The user clicks on the link in the nav, page opens, exposed filter is displayed, along with the results of the view which is everything in the db/view.

I only want the user to see the exposed filter when they click on the link to the view/page, then the user will add the 'item number' to the filter, click search/apply and see the results. I am hoping I don't have to create another view and link things.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the value of the Exposed form style to "input required". This shouldn't display the items when the first view the page.

Is that what you were after?

Comment: Let me try and see. BRB

Comment: That did not do anything - and just to confirm, I clicked "item number" in the filter criteria section, then checked the "required" checkbox in the "Filter type to expose" area.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the 'Exposed form style' setting on the right-hand side (drupal 7, not sure about d6 if that's what you are using). I have managed to achieve this before using that setting, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Just did a quick search and came up with this, seems to be the same request: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13996/how-to-hide-views-results-before-applying-exposed-filter

Comment: Ahhhhh, over there - I'm sorry, I completely misread- that worked perfectly.  I don't feel quite so bad now, because I would not have thought of looking there.  THANK YOU!!!!